# Create a new Pandas series by forward filling a sparser series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sparse Pandas series. For illustrative purposes, let us create a mock series, ts2.

```
import pandas as pd
idx2 = pd.date_range('2016-01-29', '2016-02-27', freq='W')
ts2 = pd.Series(data=[11, 9, 13, 4], index=idx2)
```

which looks like

```
2016-01-31    11
2016-02-07     9
2016-02-14    13
2016-02-21     4
```

I would like to to use ts2 to create (via forward-filling) a new series that has a different time range, say

```
idx1 = pd.date_range('2016-02-01', '2016-02-28', freq='D')
```

The new time series should look like

```
2016-02-01    11
2016-02-02    11
2016-02-03    11
2016-02-04    11
2016-02-05    11
2016-02-06    11
2016-02-07    9
2016-02-08    9
...
2016-02-08    4
```

What is a good way of doing this? Notice there is a mismatch in dates of idx1 and idx2. So to populate 2016-02-01 in idx1, you have to look up the 2016-01-31 value in ts2.

EDIT: I should mention that idx1 might not be daily but could be some collection of dates like weekdays minus public holidays in Norway or something.

Comment: Can you edit the idx1 to reference the min() value in ts2 index? Or does something prohibit this?

Comment: In general idx1 is not daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT: if idx1 has special missing days or holidays

Use `reindex` with `method='ffill'`:

```
 ts2.reindex(idx1, method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
2016-02-01    11
2016-02-02    11
2016-02-03    11
2016-02-04    11
2016-02-05    11
2016-02-06    11
2016-02-07     9
2016-02-08     9
2016-02-09     9
2016-02-10     9
2016-02-11     9
2016-02-12     9
2016-02-13     9
2016-02-14    13
2016-02-15    13
2016-02-16    13
2016-02-17    13
2016-02-18    13
2016-02-19    13
2016-02-20    13
2016-02-21     4
2016-02-22     4
2016-02-23     4
2016-02-24     4
2016-02-25     4
2016-02-26     4
2016-02-27     4
2016-02-28     4
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

## OR if idx1 is just a daily increment.

Use `resample` and `ffill`:

```
 ts2.resample('D').ffill()
```

Output:

```
2016-01-31    11
2016-02-01    11
2016-02-02    11
2016-02-03    11
2016-02-04    11
2016-02-05    11
2016-02-06    11
2016-02-07     9
2016-02-08     9
2016-02-09     9
2016-02-10     9
2016-02-11     9
2016-02-12     9
2016-02-13     9
2016-02-14    13
2016-02-15    13
2016-02-16    13
2016-02-17    13
2016-02-18    13
2016-02-19    13
2016-02-20    13
2016-02-21     4
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not have the same index as idx1. Well, in the above case, it was daily but idx1 could be only weekdays with the exception of public holidays.

Comment: @Spinor8 See edit with the use if idx with method 'ffill'.

Comment: I think the issue is `idx1` doesn't contain the min() date from `ts2.index`, thus the value is not able to be filled forward. It's possible I'm interpreting this wrong.